# Keeping band names with gdal_merge.py?

Tags: multi-band, gdal-merge

I am using gdal_merge.py to merge different mosaic rasters each contains 20 bands with different names. However, when using gdal_merge.py the bands are renamed as band1, band2, ..., band20. How can I keep the original bands name?

my code is `gdal_merge.py -n -9999 -of GTiff -o merged_Spectra spectra1.tif spectra2.tif`

Comment: There seems to be one answer that requires some Python in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609570/how-to-set-the-band-description-option-tag-of-a-geotiff-file-using-gdal-gdalw.